# Junit test not starting in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I'm pretty inexperienced with both eclipse and junit tests, so this could be a really stupid question...

When I try to run my junit test by clicking run as -> junit test, nothing happens. The console is empty, the JUnit tab shows nothing, and in the Progress tab there is a message "Launching  Finished at . communication does not exist".

What does this mean? When I run a clean package on the project, with "Skip tests" unchecked, it runs the tests, and they all pass. But I don't like to run the tests this way. It is more time consuming, and I don't get the detailed information about the tests that one gets from running them as Run As -> junit test.

Any ideas what could be wrong? I've tried googling the "communication does not exist" message, but to no avail.

Update: I've made the following test just for checking whether junit works:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    assertTrue(true  );
}
```

When I run the clean package with "Skip tests" unchecked in the run configuration, the test runs fine. That is, I get output

Running 
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec

When I change the test so assertTrue(false), it fails as expected, and the output from clean package is that it failed, with a stacktrace.

The only thing happening when I right-click the test (and class name, I've tried both), is in the Progress and JUnit-tab, pictures below:

[image: JUnig tab]

[image: Progress tab]

Arg, seems like the pictures won't open for some reason. but in summary, in the Junit tab, nothing shows, it just says runs : 0/0, Errors:0 Failures:0, and nothing more. In the Progress tab, I get the "Launching  (Finished at 08:13), and on the line below, "communication does not exist".

Comment: Are your assertions enabled? they are disabled by default. In your VM Arguments tab pass in "-ea" and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what assertions are... I put -ea in the VM arguments in the run configuration, but this didn't seem to make any change. I still get the same result.

Comment: Show us an example of one of the tests that you expect to run. Also a screen shot of what you seen when you try to run them might help.

Comment: Have the junit classes been compiled and included in the target folder? Sometimes I'll get a NoClassDefError with Junit tests in eclipse, but then usually a 'mvn clean install' will fix this and then eclipse should be able to run them.

Comment: The class has been compiled and included in the jar-file.

Comment: FOCUS! Junit works via mvn. Dont ask for exceptions.

Comment: Has the project-icon an blue M?

Comment: @PeterRader: sorry, I don't understand what you mean by the first exceptions-answer? The project icon has a blue M, yes.

Comment: I tried renaming the test to myTest, in case there is a naming error, but still same problem. But class is also named blablaTest.

Answer (score 2):

In my case in run configuration I put it as junit4 ran well

[image]

Comment: Correct, by default JUnit 5 is used (jupiter version)